# Add image from database after building jar

Tags: java

So, I have a java program which reads a MySQL database. It reads lots of things from there and, one of them, is the path for images.

Is there a way I can add an image path in this database and make a built jar show it without rebuilding?

Comment: Depends how often the app picks up the image path. If it does it all the time you'll be fine

Comment: I don't see the relation between the DB and the jar. I suppose you don't hard-code the path(s) in the Java code itself, so rebuilding should not be necessary at all. All your jar need to do is to use a JDBC driver to reach the database and add to / read from it.

Comment: Yes, I am not hard-coding the path. And it works when it's running inside NetBeans. But once I build it, the image does not appear anymore. No changes in code or database.